# How to render HTML tags from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags

I have a mysql database that stores text from ckeditor which comes with html tags. When i try to display the text using javascript it shows the tags on the page without properly formatting it e.g

```
<p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
<p><i>This text is italic</i></p>
<p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
$("#topHeading1").text(item.articleHeading);
                $("#topArticle1").text(item.articleHeading);

                $("#topStory1Heading").text(item.articleHeading);
                $("#topStory1Date").text(item.articleDate);
                $("#topStory1Author").text(item.articleAuthors);
                $("#topStory1Content").text(item.articleBody);

                $("#topHeading1Image").attr('src', 'assets/img/' + item.articleImage);
                $("#topArticle1Image").attr('src', 'assets/img/' + item.articleImage);
                $("#topStory1Image").attr('src', 'assets/img/' + item.articleImage);
```

THE PHP CODE

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $articleItem = array(
        "articleId" => $row["articleId"],
        "articleHeading" => $row["articleHeading"],
        "articleBody" => nl2br($row["articleBody"]),
        "articleAuthors" => $row["articleAuthors"],
        "articleDate" => $row["articleDate"],
        "articleImage" => $row["articleImage"],
        "articleLocation" => $row["articleLocation"]
    );

    $list[] = $articleItem;
}
```

The HTML code

```
<div class="category_article_content" id="topStory1Content"> 
                                                   Content
                                                </div>
```

How do i render it properly on my website .

Comment: Sounds like you want to set `html` instead of `text`.

Comment: uses `dom.element.innerHTML = yourhtml` or `jquery: $('div').load(yourhtml)`

Comment: Directly into the HTML: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @Sphinx Thank you for your answer it worked , please put it as an answer so that i can mark it as correct. So that the next person who has this problem they will c the correct answer. Also so that u can get the points for your contribution